# Trouble serving PHP project in VS Code

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code, laravel-artisan, uncaught-exception

I have a problem that has a couple of developers confused at the current moment.

Its a laravel project (laravel v4), and it contains some parts that are beyond my current comprehension (familiar with php but not with laravel framework). The project root contains a laravel folder, along with a mysql folder for database related files, and a folder that contains the website root (separate from the laravel folder); it looks like so:

- project_root {
  --.git
  --.vscode
  --laravel
  --mysql
  --site
  }

within the site root, from vs code, I am attempting to 'serve the project' with the use of a VS Code extension called *PHP Server*, and this is done by simply right clicking a file within the project and choosing 'serve project'. When the project serve, and the site opens in browser - it always fails to properly display a page. Things like stylesheets aren't loading, and PHP isn't being parsed correctly and comments are appearing in the rendered html.

I've tried an alternative to this, by using the command `php artisan serve` within the laravel folder of the project; however, this also fails for reasons that I am currently trying to figure out. When entering the artisan serve command, I get in response:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ErrorException: Notice: Undefined index: SERVER_NAME in C:\_SourceControl\Organization\Client\project_root\laravel\app\config\app.php line 16 in C:\_SourceControl\Organization\Client\project_root\laravel\app\config\app.php:16
Stack trace:
#0 C:\_SourceControl\Organization\Client\project_root\laravel\app\config\app.php(16): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\ErrorHandler->handle(8, 'Undefined index...', 'C:\\_SourceContr...', 16, Array)
#1 C:\_SourceControl\Organization\Client\project_root\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem.php(52): require('C:\\_SourceContr...')
#2 C:\_SourceControl\Organization\Client\project_root\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Config\FileLoader.php(77): Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem->getRequire('C:\\_SourceContr...')
#3 C:\_SourceControl\Organization\Client\project_root\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Config\Repository.php(152): Illuminate\Config\FileLoader->load('production', 'app', NULL)
#4 C:\_SourceControl\Organization\Client\project_root\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Config\Repository.php(99): Illuminate\Config\Reposito in C:\_SourceControl\Organization\Client\project_root\laravel\app\config\app.php on line 16
```

And here is what that error is pointing to:

```
'debug' => strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], 'site url would be here') === false,
```

To follow up on that, my co-developers who work on this have the same exact files, just on a different machine, but don't run into this error when using the right-click + 'serve project' or the `php artisan serve` command. There isn't a .env file used with this project, so we can't seem to figure out the cause of the exception `Undefined index: SERVER_NAME`. The developer who originally set the site and project up has since left, and none of us can seem to figure out the cause or solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Create a .env file with content

`<?php`
    return array(
      'DEBUG'           => true,
    );
if you are running locally and false if running in production. 
In your `app.php` change `'debug' => strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], 'site url would be here') === false,` into `'debug' => $_ENV['DEBUG'],`